# Trouble using case class for multiple fields in POST body Finatra

Tags: scala, rest, case-class, finatra

I am working on a simple Finatra API example, but having trouble using a case class for the POST request when using more than one field in the request body.

Here is an example of my case class and controller:

```
class SaleResource extends Controller {
  post("/sales") { sale: Sale =>
    s"$sale"
  }
}

case class Sale(
                 user: Option[String],
                 streetAddress: Option[String]
               )
```

I send a post request to that route with the following request body JSON:

```
{
"user": "Foo Barrington",
"streetAddress":"Baz Street"
}
```

The response:
`Sale(Some(Foo Barrington),None)`

The response shows that the user is being properly deserialized, but for some reason I cannot get the streetAddress field to populate.

Also, I noticed when I set either of these fields to `String` instead of `Option[String]` I only get unsuccessful 500 responses.

Things I have tried:

- case statements matching `Some(streetAddress)` to that fields string value or "none found" when it is `None`. In these cases it still is saying `streetAddress` is `None` when it is not.
- Making the request with both `curl` and Postman.

I can always access the user field from the `Sales` object, but never the `streetAddress` (or any other field from the request body for that matter if I add test elements to the case class.

I would expect both fields to be recognized since they are both provided in the request. I am newer to Scala/Finatra in general, so it is possible I am just using the Finatra library or Case classes incorrectly.

EDIT:
It seems as if changing the field names to not be mixed/camelcase fixes all issues, but this seems like odd behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finatra uses Jackson library behind the scenes. The default configuration uses `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` which seems like:

```
{
  "user": "Foo Barrington",
  "street_address":"Baz Street"
}
```

You need to change it to `PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` to parse that JSON.
In order to do that, you need to define a custom `FinatraJacksonModule` and tell the app to
use it.

```
object CustomFinatraJacksonModule extends FinatraJacksonModule {
  override val propertyNamingStrategy = PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
}



class MyFinatraHttpServer extends HttpServer {
  override protected def jacksonModule: Module = CustomFinatraJacksonModule
}
```

[Jackson Integration](https://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/json/index.html) provides more information about the topic.